# Is it possible to hook into hostnamectl?

Tags: systemd, hostname

Let's say I want to run a script when the hostname is change on a machine with `hostnamectl set-hostname NAME`

Is there a way to hook into this? How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.  I don't have full instructions. (Feel free to post any script you write etc, and take due credit for it :-).

`hostnamectl` / `hostnamed` does not run scripts.  When you change the hostname using `hostnamectl`, `hostnamed` emits a dbus signal called `PropertyChanged`.  You could hook up to the dbus signal, using something like `dbus-monitor`.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/150790/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-a-dbus-signal

The link above describes starting the dbus-monitor script when you log in to a graphical environment.  It does this using an XDG autostart.  If you want your dbus-monitor script to run without you logging in to a graphical environment, you could use a simple `systemd` service instead.